# jQuery doesn't execute when window size change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just write a script to auto positioning an element on my page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll < 180) {
            $(".header-bottom").removeClass("scroll-menu");
            if ($(window).width() > 991) {
                $(".header_user_top").css("position", "absolute");
                $(".header_user_top").css("top", "initial");
                $(".header_user_top").css("right", "60px");
                $(".header_user_top").css("z-index", "1");
            }
        } else {
            $(".header-bottom").addClass("scroll-menu");
            if ($(window).width() > 991) {
                var rightContainer = ($(window).width() - ($('#header div.header-bottom div.container').offset().left + $('#header div.header-bottom div.container').outerWidth()));
                $(".header_user_top").css("position", "fixed");
                $(".header_user_top").css("top", "-22px");
                $(".header_user_top").css("right", rightContainer+60+"px");
                $(".header_user_top").css("z-index", "99");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

It's working but if I resize browser window the script doesn't reload.

If I refresh the page it's working.

I have add `window.onresize = function(){ location.reload(); }`to my script to fix this problem but I'm looking for a better solution.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `on` function to call multiple event:

```
   $(window).on("load resize scroll",function(e){
    // do something
    }
```

Comment: Ya great but then OP should unwrap it from ready handler otherwise `load` event would be useless here

Answer (score 2):

Call function which is handling size on windows.resize also

```
function handleSize(){
   // You code to handle size
 }
window.resize=handleSize();
```